# How can I simplify this rational function for graphing by translation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions

I've actually struggled with how to properly simplify this rational function, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. It's part of my precalculus class/section on graphing rational functions by translation:

$f(x)=\frac{-x}{7x+5}$

I can get along OK with simpler such rational functions, but this one is throwing me for a loop, because of the (-x) in the numerator.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm sorry for any formatting problems in advance, as I'm new to this site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find an equivalent form which you can already graph by translations:
$$f(x)=\frac{-x}{7x+5}=\ -\frac{x+5/7}{7x+5}\ +\frac{5/7}{7x+5}\ =\\
= -\frac17\ +\frac 5{49x+35}\,.
 $$

Comment: This helps a great deal. It's the intermediate steps that I'm still kind of scratching my head over, which is frustrating, because I've done this with other exercises many times. Would you care to explain how you "decomposed" (for the lack of knowing a better word) the fraction in the second step? Or maybe tell me what I should search for to find an answer elsewhere? Thanks very much!